# No lib64 directory in python virtualenv with WSL

Tags: python, ffmpeg, virtualenv, windows-subsystem-for-linux, site-packages

I am using WSL on windows 10. I created a python3.6 virtual environment using virtualenv. When trying to import the "arcade" library I'm getting the following error:

`Unable to find match for ffmpeg sound library at expected location: /home/nick/python-virtualenvs/final_projects/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet_ffmpeg2/linux_x86_64/libavcodec.so.58.*`

Although I have pyglet_ffmpeg2 in lib sit packages, it turns out I don't even have a lib64 directory. I have confirmed that this is 64-bit python using:

`print ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_voidp)`

It actually looks as though I don't have 64-bit packages at all, even within base python for example, there is no `/usr/lib64/`.

Anyone have any ideas? My instinct is this is a WSL quirk, or at least something specific to how I have it installed. A quick google search did not provide any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experienced the same issue working with a Xubuntu VM. It looks like they're aware of it and making a fix at some point.

In the short term you can hack together a [quick fix](https://github.com/pvcraven/arcade/issues/350) in pyglet's `loader.py` by commenting out line 55 ('path = path.replace("/lib/", "/lib64/")`). This isn't a great way to fix it, but it will get you rolling for now.